# How can I write a module to handle ExpressJS session?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I'm new to ExpressJS (just 3 months) and I'm trying to make a project to get some hands on practice of what I have learned so far.

I have tried writing a module to handle express session. But it does not seem to work - no error as well as no response.

The code is:

```
var express = require("express");
var session = require('express-session');
var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);

// MySQL Session Configuration
const mySQLSessionConfiguration = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 1234,
    user: 'thisIsNotMyRealUsername',
    password: 'neitherThisIsMyRealPassword',
    database: 'aDatabase'
};

// Create Session
module.exports = function (){
    return (session({
    store: new MySQLStore(mySQLSessionConfiguration),
    secret: 'LOL',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
    }));
};
```

and in my index.js file:

```
app.use(require("./modules/session.js"));
```

// The code works fine if I write this directly inside the index.js but I want to write a module - I wanna learn.

Error in CLI: none
Error in Browser: none but nothing. I mean neither a response. Keeps waiting

Whats wrong here. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by passing the "app" directly into the module instead of returning the session from the module.

The fixed code looks like this:

```
// var express = require("express"); -- not required at all
var session = require('express-session');
var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);

// MySQL Session Configuration
const mySQLSessionConfiguration = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 1234,
    user: 'thisIsNotMyRealUsername',
    password: 'neitherThisIsMyRealPassword',
    database: 'aDatabase'
};

// Create Session
module.exports = function (app){    // app received :D
    app.use(session({               // app.use instead of return
    store: new MySQLStore(mySQLSessionConfiguration),
    secret: 'LOL',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
    }));
};
```

and in index.js

```
var alpha = require("./modules/session.js")(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have replicate your scenario on a sample application and wrote the following code in "session.js" file

```
var clientsession = require('client-sessions');

module.exports = function (){
  return (clientsession({
    cookieName: 'session',
    secret: 'secret',
    duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
    activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
    }));
};
```

then in server.js I use it as following:

```
app.use(require('./session.js'));
```

Its working absolutely find. 
Can you share your error log for more details?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your time. I've fixed the problem. Instead of returning the session object. I have passed the "app" directly into the module and then used "app.use(all the session related stuff I was returning);"

Answer (score 0):

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');    
var session = require('express-session');
var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);

var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : '< MySQL username >',
  password : '< MySQL password >',
  database : '<your database name>'
});

connection.connect();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  secret: 'supersecret',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: new mySQLStore(mysqlConnection: mysql.connection),
  cookie: { maxAge: 1000 } //whatever you'd like
}));
```

This is how I usually do it in express, with express-session.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use the same way. But I just wanted to make a module so that I can clear my concepts - I'm new to express.

The problem has been resolved.